# Linux: Skip grepping files if file path name already exists in the input file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am very new to shell scripting, it would be great if I can get some help with the below question.

I have thousands of folders/sub-folders and files under a directory `~/home/dir`, with new files added all the time. (Unfortunately the timing of the new files being added is random).

In this folder I only want to grep the new files that have been added. To know which file is new and which file is old, I store from a previous grep action the path names of the files I have already grepped in a txt file called `path.txt` in the directory `~/home`.

for example in the path.txt file, I have something like this

```
/home/dir/b1/file50.txt
/home/dir/abc/file52.txt
/home/dir/det/file539.txt
/home/dir/br/com_file6551.txt
/home/dir/n12/d2/c_file251.txt
/home/dir/fg/file51.txt
etc etc..
```

Is there any way where I can pass the path names from the `path.txt` file as input to grep, so that if the file pathname already exists then it skips grepping that file.

Or maybe is there any other easier way to skip grepping these old files?

Comment: No, `grep` doesn't take an exclusion list. You'll need to use something like `find` to generate the list of files, pipe that to `fgrep -v -x -f path.txt`, and pipe that to `xargs grep pattern`.

Comment: And if you're using `find`, you can use the `-newer` option to select files newer than a timestamp file, instead of using an exclusion list.

Comment: @ Barmar, I like your suggestion of using find and piping it to fgrep and so on.

Currently i just grep pattern in all files everytime with my script, which i think is not efficient.

With your suggestion by using "find" I am still looking up all files, and then fgrep -v is trying to inverse match the pathnames and then based on the new ones it finds another xargs grep for the pattern only in those new files.

One important question: Is this really more efficient than the current method of simply grepping all files?

Comment: The expensive part is usually grepping the files, so anything that reduces the number of files fed to `grep` is usually more efficient.

Comment: @ Barmar, thank you very much, it is indeed faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barmar's suggestion is often faster than `grep`ing all of the files. the more of the paths there are in `path.txt`, the greater the speedup.

here's a bit i'll add: filtering with `find -print0 | fgrep -v -x -f` won't work, so how can you handle spaces in paths after filtering? (`xargs -I{} grep <pattern> "{}"` would work, but is two orders of magnitude slower.)

```
find /home/dir -type f |
  fgrep -v -x -f path.txt |
  tr '\n' '\0' | 
  xargs -0 grep '<pattern>'
```

test setup: 21997 files, ~20k each, some have spaces in paths. i ran each command several times and used fastest time to control for disk caching.

```
grep -R asd *                                      0.302s
find * -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep asd         0.325s

find * -type f |
  fgrep -v -x -f ../5000paths.lst |                0.228s
  tr '\n' '\0' | 
  xargs -0 grep asd

find * -type f |
  fgrep -v -x -f ../10000paths.lst |               0.269s
  ...

find * -type f |
  fgrep -v -x -f ../15000paths.lst |               0.189s
  ...

find * -type f |
  fgrep -v -x -f ../20000paths.lst |               0.094s
  ...

find * -type f |
  fgrep -v -x -f ../all21997paths.lst |            0.059s
  ...
```